# how to prevent rendering duplicates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I have this app that I am working on that generates notes of whatever I type and add in the create area. I tried nested mapping using the following code that generates 3 notes (intended) with each add click.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
          {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
            return (<>
              <Note
              onAdd={addNote}
                key={index}
                id={index}
                title={noteItem.title}
                content={noteItem.content}
                onDelete={deleteNote}
              />
              {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <Note
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    title={noteItem.title}
                    content={noteItem.content}
                    onDelete={deleteNote}
                  />
                );
              })}</>
            );
          })}
        </React.Fragment>);
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the issue is that when i press add again (second time after already adding 3 notes) instead of adding 3 notes, it adds like 11 new notes (some new and some of the previous added again). you can test it by copying the above code in the App.jsx in this link. https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-part-3-completed-forked-8zs84v?file=/src/components/App.jsx:0-1628

I want it to add only 3 notes with a single click. (The components have to be nested as shown) I am trying to add an if condition where to stop rendering those multiple extra components but I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're nesting inside each `.map`. So when you're on the first `.map` and you're rendering out the first element, that second `.map` will now go through all of the elements that are contained within `notes` and render out each element. This will happen with every nested `.map` that you have.

Lets run through what your first run through the first element would be if `notes` contained 2 elements:

- Map 1 would just render out one `Notes` component.
- Map 2 would render out 2 `Notes` components, `Note` for the first element and the second element.
- Map 3 would render out 4 `Notes` components. One for the first element and one for the second element WHEN Map 2 is on it's first element. When Map 2 is on it's second element, it will render out a `Notes` component again for both the first and the second elements of `notes`

So in total, you would have rendered out the first element 4 times and the second element 3 times for a total of 7 elements on the page when Map 1 is just on its first element. It would run through all of this again when Map 1 is rendering out for the second element; which should net you 14 `Notes` components.

To accomplish your ask of just rendering out 3 elements, I would either just forcefully add in extra elements to your `setNotes` function:

```
setNotes(prevNotes => {
    return [...prevNotes, newNote, newNote, newNote];
});
```

but if you wanted to keep that pure, you could just un-nest your `.map`'s so that they are standalones.

If you need them to be nested, then you would need to compare the indexes at each `.map` level

```
{notes.map((noteItem, indexOne) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Note
              key={indexOne}
              id={indexOne}
              title={noteItem.title}
              content={noteItem.content}
              onDelete={deleteNote}
            />
            {notes.map((noteItem, indexTwo) => {
              return (
                <>
                  {
                    indexOne === indexTwo
                    ? <Note
                    onAdd={addNote}
                      key={indexTwo}
                      id={indexTwo}
                      title={noteItem.title}
                      content={noteItem.content}
                      onDelete={deleteNote}
                    />
                    : ''
                  }
                  {notes.map((noteItem, indexThree) => {
                    return (
                      indexOne === indexThree && indexTwo === indexThree
                      ? <Note
                          key={indexThree}
                          id={indexThree}
                          title={noteItem.title}
                          content={noteItem.content}
                          onDelete={deleteNote}
                        />
                      : ''
                    );
                  })}
                </>
              );
            })}
        </React.Fragment>);
})}
```